# Need help on working with parametric function

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, parametric-functions

Here is an ODE solved by ParametricNDSolveValue solver.I got the solution.
Now, I need to solve these two equations:

```
p1 = 10 h - l;
p2 = 10 h1;
```

where `h` and `h1` go from 2 to 5. Left to me. `l` is obtained from solving `s1`, where

```
l = 4 π j NIntegrate[r^2 Exp[-First[s1[sol]][r]], {r, 0, R}];
```

So, I need to get `p1` for different values of `l`. To do that I need to vary `z` an `g`; let's say `{z, 100, 400, 50}` and `{g, 0.023, 0.134}`. Then for these values, there is a corresponding `l` to pass to `p1`. After getting `p1` and `p2`, I want to know where `p1 - p2  == 0` by means of inspecting a  3D contour plot. See the following link [1](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/HighlightTheIntersectionOfTwoSurfaces.html).

```
Z = 800; 
g = Rationalize[0.0238, 0];
k2 = Rationalize[0.000194519, 0];
ϵ = 10^-4; 
R = Rationalize[1.5472, 0];
j = .00001271;

s1 = 
  ParametricNDSolveValue[
    {y''[r] + 2 y'[r]/r == k2 Sinh[y[r]], 
     y[ϵ] == y0, y'[ϵ] == 0, 
     WhenEvent[r == 1, y'[r] -> y'[r] + Z g]}, 
    {y, y'}, {r, ϵ, R}, {y0}, 
    Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", WorkingPrecision -> 30];

sol = FindRoot[Last[s1[y0]][R], {y0, -11.25, -11.}, 
   Evaluated -> False][[1, 2]]

Plot[First[s1[sol]][r], {r, ϵ, R}, 
  AxesLabel -> {r, y}, 
  ImageSize -> Large, 
  LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, Medium}]

Plot[
  Evaluate @ Table[TooltipFirst[s1[sol]][r], y0] 
  {z, 100, 400, 50}, {g, 0.023, 0.134}, {r, 0, R}] 

l = 4 π j NIntegrate[r^2 Exp[-First[s1[sol]][r]], {r, 0, R}];
p1 = 10 h - l1 ;
p2 = 10 h1 ; 

ContourPlot3D[
  {p1 == 0, p2 == 0}, {h, -2, 2}, {h1, -2, 2}, {l, -2, 2},  
  MeshFunctions -> {Function[{h, h1, l, f}, p1 - p2]},  
  MeshStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}}, 
  Mesh -> {{0}},  
  ContourStyle ->  Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.5], Specularity[White, 30]]]
```

My issues that `l` depends on the `s1` and therefore on `z`, `g`, etc. I believe I need to use `Do` or `Table`, but I do not know how? Please help.

Comment: `sol` has 2 parameters: `u0` and `c`. Therefore `l` also should depend on `u0` and `c`. And you try to `ContourPlot` with two additional variables `h` and `h1`, I dont't understand what is your goal.

Comment: @Alx I updated the Q.

Comment: You write `log[2]`. Do you really mean `Log[2]`?

Comment: yes I meant  'Log[2]'

Comment: @m_goldberg To make the code simple : assume `p1 = 10h-l` and `p2 = 10 h1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood your task, but my thought on this.

```
z = 800; g = Rationalize[0.0238, 0];
k2 = Rationalize[0.000194519, 0];
ϵ = 10^-4; R = Rationalize[1.5472, 0];
j = .00001271;

s1 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y''[r] + 2 y'[r]/r == k2 Sinh[y[r]], 
    y[ϵ] == y0, y'[ϵ] == 0, 
    WhenEvent[r == 1, y'[r] -> y'[r] + z1 g1]}, {y, 
    y'}, {r, ϵ, R}, {y0, z1, g1}, 
   Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", WorkingPrecision -> 30];
```

So, I added two more parameters `z1` and `g1` (renamed to not to confuse with some initial constants `z` and `g`).

Then I define helper function for use inside `FindRoot`, it accepts numerical arguments only:

```
s2[y0_?NumericQ, z1_?NumericQ, g1_?NumericQ] := Last[s1[y0, z1, g1]]
```

Now we can compute `y0` values for different `z1` and `g1`:

```
tab = Flatten[
  Quiet@Table[{y0 /. FindRoot[s2[y0, z, g][R], {y0, -10}], z, g},
  {z, 100, 400, 50}, {g, {0.023, 0.134}}], 1]
```

and corresponding `l` values:

```
l = 4 π j NIntegrate[r^2 Exp[-First[s1[##]][r]], {r, 0, R}] & @@@ tab
```

What to do next, how to visualize? One can make `ContourPlot`:

```
ContourPlot[
 Evaluate@Table[10 h - l1 == 10 h1, {l1, l}], {h, 2, 5}, {h1, 2, 5},
 FrameLabel -> {h, h1}]
```

[image]

Or `ListPlot3D`:

```
ListPlot3D[
 Flatten[Table[{h1, l1, h1 + l1/10}, {h1, 2, 5, 0.1}, {l1, l}], 1], 
 AxesLabel -> {h1, l1, h}]
```

[image]

**EDIT**

To answer additional request: `z = 160/h, g = 0.0714/h1`. Make corresponding changes:

```
s1 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y''[r] + 2 y'[r]/r == k2 Sinh[y[r]], 
        y[ϵ] == y0, y'[ϵ] == 0, 
        WhenEvent[r == 1, y'[r] -> y'[r] + 160/h 0.0714/h1]}, {y, 
        y'}, {r, ϵ, R}, {y0, h, h1}, 
       Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", WorkingPrecision -> 30];

s2[y0_?NumericQ, h_?NumericQ, h1_?NumericQ] := Last[s1[y0, h, h1]]
ff[h_?NumericQ, h1_?NumericQ] := y0 /. FindRoot[s2[y0, h, h1][R], {y0, -10}]
ll[h_?NumericQ, h1_?NumericQ] := 4 π j NIntegrate[r^2 Exp[-First[s1[ff[h, h1], h, h1]][r]],{r, 0, R}]
```

Now we are ready to plot contour of `10 h - ll[h, h1] - 10 h1 == 0`:

```
ListContourPlot[
 Flatten[Table[{h, h1, 10 h - ll[h, h1] - 10 h1}, {h, 2, 5, 0.1}, {h1,
     2, 5, 0.1}], 1], Contours -> {0}, ContourShading -> None, 
 ContourStyle -> Thick, FrameLabel -> {h, h1}, BaseStyle -> 12]
```

[image]

**FINAL EDIT**

```
k2 = Rationalize[0.000194519, 0];
ϵ = 10^-4; R = Rationalize[1.5472, 0];
j = .00001271;

s1 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y''[r] + 2 y'[r]/r == k2 Sinh[y[r]], 
    y[ϵ] == y0, y'[ϵ] == 0, 
    WhenEvent[r == 1, y'[r] -> y'[r] + 160/h 0.0714/h1]}, {y, 
    y'}, {r, ϵ, R}, {y0, h, h1}, 
   Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", WorkingPrecision -> 30];

s2[y0_?NumericQ, h_?NumericQ, h1_?NumericQ] := Last[s1[y0, h, h1]]
ff[h_?NumericQ, h1_?NumericQ] := 
 y0 /. FindRoot[s2[y0, h, h1][R], {y0, -10}]
ll[h_?NumericQ, h1_?NumericQ] := 
 4 π j NIntegrate[
   r^2 Exp[-First[s1[ff[h, h1], h, h1]][r]], {r, 0, R}]
```

To speed-up computation (`FindRoot` and `NIntegrate` are very expensive for continuous plotting) I suggest using `Interpolation` of `ll`:

```
llinterp = 
 Interpolation[
  Flatten[Table[{{h, h1}, ll[h, h1]}, {h, 2, 5, 0.1}, {h1, 2, 5, 
     0.1}], 1]]
```

Now we can define `p1` and `p2` via `llinterp` (as of last comment of OP):

```
p1 = 10 h - llinterp[h, h1] + u
p2 = -u + 10 h1 llinterp[h, h1]
```

and see what are `ContourPlot3D`s:

```
ContourPlot3D[p1, {h, 2, 5}, {h1, 2, 5}, {u, 2, 10}, Contours -> 5, 
PlotLegends -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {h, h1, u}]
```

[image]

```
ContourPlot3D[p2, {h, 2, 5}, {h1, 2, 5}, {u, 2, 10}, Contours -> 5, 
PlotLegends -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {h, h1, u}]
```

[image]

Colors in lenends correspond to values of `p1`, `p2`.

Apparently, with given ranges of variables (`h, h1, u`) we can not fulfil conditions `p1 = 0` and `p2 = 0`. Moreover, these conditions are conflicting: to decreese `p1` one has to decrease `h`, but for `p2` situation is opposite. So, OP should think about conditions and/or variables' ranges.

We can also plot intersection (`p1 == p2`):

```
ContourPlot3D[p1 == p2, {h, 2, 5}, {h1, 2, 5}, {u, 2, 10}, 
AxesLabel -> {h, h1, u}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Alx.I do not see when `p1-p2=0`

Comment: Lines in `ContourPlot` correspond to `p1-p2 == 0` which is the same as `10 h - l1 == 10 h1`. In `ListPlot3D` I plot `h` vs `h1` and `l1` as a solution to `10 h - l1 == 10 h1` ->`h==h1 - l1/10`.

Comment: I was expecting to see intersection of two surfaces !! which indicates where the zero pint of `p1- p2`.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand. Let's clarify. `p1` and `p2` are actually planes in terms of `h` and `h1`. You can make this plot: `ContourPlot3D[Evaluate[(10 h == 10 h1 - #) & /@ l], {h, 2, 5}, {h1, 2, 5}, {z, -10, 10}]` and see that `p1 - p2 == 0` generates series of planes, and in cross-section (in `h - h1` plane) this gives exactly what I showed in `ContourPlot` in answer. If it is not what you assumed to be, sorry I have no more ideas.

Comment: Thanks Alx. I got your points. What if `z `and `g` function of `h` and `h1` : `z=160/h` and g=0.0714/h1`. Could you please help me with that?

Comment: I edited answer to meet your new requirements.

Comment: I really appreciate that, to do 3D plot: `ContourPlot3D[Evaluate[(h1,h,10 h == 10 h1 - #) & /@ ll], {h, 2, 5}, {h1, 2, 5}, {z, -10, 10}]` Am I right? I did not get the solution.

Comment: What is `z` in your last comment? Is it dummy "vertical" direction, because we just changed `z` to `z=160/h`? I edited last answer and added `_?NumericalQ` tests to `ff` and `ll` definitions, which is essential for using them in smooth plotting. So, `ll` is smooth function, not descrete one,  hence `/@ ll` is of no use here. You can write like `ContourPlot3D[10 h - ll[h, h1] == 10 h1, {h,2,5}, {h1,2,5}, {z,-10,10}]`, but if `z` is dummy it has not much sense as compared to plane `ContourPlot` without `z`. The smooth curve is the same as in my answer with discrete `h` and `h1`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help @Alx. One more thing, If I add an extra variables to p1 and p2, let say: `p1 = u-10 h - l[h,h1]` and `p2 = u+10 h1 l[h,h1]`. Now to see `p1-p2==0` `ContourPlot3D{[p1==0, p2==0}, {h,2,5}, {h1,2,5}, {u,2,10}]` gave me an error message `ContourPlot3D called with 1 argument; 4 arguments are expected`. Could you help in that?

Comment: `ContourPlot3D[{p1==0, p2==0},{h,2,5},{h1,2,5},{u,2,10}]` should work. But `p1 - p2 == 0` is not the same as `p1 == 0, p2 == 0`. If you want to see `p1 - p2 == 0` you should write that condition exactly: `ContourPlot3D[p1 - p2 ==0, {h,2,5},{h1,2,5},{u,2,10}]`. Note that with your particular new definitions of `p1` and `p2` the dependence on `u` is cancelled in this case.

Comment: I do not want to cancel `u`. In other words : can I use this : ContourPlot3D[{p1 == 0, p2 == 0}, {h, 2, 5}, {h1, 2, 5}, {u, 2, 10},  MeshFunctions -> {Function[{h, h1, u, f}, p1 - p2]},  MeshStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}}, Mesh -> {{0}},  ContourStyle ->  Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.5], Specularity[White, 30]]] where `p1 = 10 h - l[h,h1`]+u` and p2 = `-u+10 h1 l[h,h1]`? I want to see highlight the intersection of two Surfaces.[https://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/HighlightTheIntersectionOfTwoSurfaces.html]

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Yes. it is not working. General::ovfl: Overflow occurred in computation.

Comment: See my last edit. You can use this technique if you change conditions, ranges etc.

Comment: Thanks so much. I really appreciate what we have done. Great gob! +1. Last thing as you comment out `FindRoot` and `NIntegrate` are very expensive for continuous plotting) I suggest using Interpolation. Is there better way than Interpolation to reduce the computation time. Because with `Interpolation` still the time is too much for certain parameters.

Comment: The main time comsumption goes from making `Table` of `ll[h, h1]`, and `Interpolation` per se is very fast. And this is much faster than direct using `ll[h, h1]` in plotting commands. I have no more to say how to improve performance further. You may ask another question and probably someone with more Mathematica knowledge will answer that.